# Calculating t-inverse in apache commons

Tags: java, statistics

I need to calculate a t statistic for a java app. I'm using the Apache Commons library but can't find the implementation I need. I can get it in Excel with the TINV command, 1-the confidence level, and the sample count-1. For example, with the values 10, 24, and 19; and a 90% confidence level, I get a t-statistic of 2.9199... That's the number I need to reproduce in java.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excel `TINV(probability, deg_freedom)` analogue:

```
new org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.TDistribution(deg_freedom).
inverseCumulativeProbability(probability)
```

Cheers

Comment: Many thanks for both good answers. I was making it harder than it needed to be (of course). This works great.

Comment: Download from here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi

Answer (score 0):

For Java try [jSci](http://jsci.sourceforge.net/). It has a class for handling the T-Distribution: http://jsci.sourceforge.net/api/JSci/maths/statistics/TDistribution.html#inverse(double). You might like to try out a [python port](https://github.com/rubzo/marky/blob/master/tinv.py) either.